# Node.js: express not working?

Tags: node.js, express

I installed express, and it worked just fine:

```
...
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.1.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.2.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-0.0.4.tgz
express@4.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express
├── methods@0.1.0
├── parseurl@1.0.1
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── debug@0.8.0
├── cookie-signature@1.0.3
├── range-parser@1.0.0
├── fresh@0.2.2
├── qs@0.6.6
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── cookie@0.1.0
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.2
├── type-is@1.0.0 (mime@1.2.11)
├── send@0.2.0 (mime@1.2.11)
├── accepts@1.0.0 (mime@1.2.11, negotiator@0.3.0)
└── serve-static@1.0.1 (send@0.1.4)
```

But then i do:

```
express testapp
-bash: express: command not found
```

It's as if express is not installed. What's up with that?

Just FYI, i have OSX if that makes any difference?

Comment: did you use -g when you installed?

Comment: Tried with -g and without it. With sudo and without it.

Comment: Wont work without sudo though...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The new version of Express (4.0) does not itself have a `bin` folder.  You have to install `express-generator` to get the setup functionality.

Express 4.0 made significant changes.  Specifically, moving middlewares and helpers into external modules.

If you need to get something up and running right away, you should install Express 3 and then learn how to get Express 4 running when you have more time.

First, make sure you have `./node_modules/.bin` in your $PATH.  Then...

```
npm install "express@3.x"
express
```

Or if you have time to learn the differences in Express 4 then you can get up and running by installing `express-generator`.

```
npm install express-generator
express
```

**IMPORTANT**: make sure you have `./node_modules/.bin` in your shell $PATH variable.  Executable files in Node modules are linked in the `./node_modules/.bin` directory.  Having that in your path makes it easy to run those executables without typing the whole path and without adding them globally.  Adding them globally is a bad idea if you work with multiple projects and need to maintain backwards compatibility with old projects.

**TIP**: You can find the [list of Express middlewares and helpers on Github](https://github.com/expressjs).

Comment: Noooo, nooo, it's still not working! The command executed just fine, even without sudo, but when i type express testapp i still get command not found...

Comment: Make sure you have `./node_modules/.bin` in your $PATH.

Comment: $ npm install -g "express@3.x"

Comment: Much better to install things locally.  Someday you're going to want to work with express 4 but you'll still want your old express 3 projects to continue working as well.

Comment: In plain English what does it mean to "make sure you have ./node_modules/.bin in your $PATH"?

Comment: In Unix and Windows based systems the path is the list of directories to search for an executable when you issue a command on the command line.  You can pretty easily find specifics on managing your path via Google.

Comment: I tried to follow these directions and ./node_modules/.bin is not in my $PATH ... what do I do?

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I got my express app to work. I first ran

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

Then I created my app with

```
express app_name
```

Where `app_name` is obviously the name of your app.

Then I installed the dependancies.

```
cd app_name && npm install
```

Then to run the app I did

```
DEBUG=app_name ./bin/www
```

The prompts were generated by the system and you can copy and paste them. Then you visit

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Here is my app working locally

[image]

Comment: Followed these same steps, but the app doesn't run. It says that the `require('../app')` inside `./bin/www` failed. I don't understand why it is not working.